# How to avoid black lines when using BufferStrategy in java

Tags: java, swing

Following a guide that was released in Nov, 2015.  I have copied his code verbatim at this point and it still won't work for me.  Has something been deprecated?

I have 3 buffers (call them 1,2, and 3).  When 2 and 3 are drawn to the screen they have black lines on the top and left sides of the screen.  This same code works fine with two buffers.

Bug footage:  https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/GraveCompetentArmyworm

```
package field;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    private Canvas canvas=new Canvas();

    public Main() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setBounds(0,0,1000,1000);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        add(canvas);
        setVisible(true);

        canvas.createBufferStrategy(3);
        BufferStrategy buffert = canvas.getBufferStrategy();

        int p=0;
        int ap=0;
        while(p<1000) {
            if (ap==100){
                p++;
                ap=0;
            }
            ap++;
            buffert=canvas.getBufferStrategy();
            Graphics g = buffert.getDrawGraphics();
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

            g.fillOval(p+100, 200, 50, 50);

            buffert.show(); 
        }
    }

//  public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
//      super.paint(graphics);
//      graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
//      graphics.fillOval(100, 100, 100, 100);
//      
//  }



    public static void main(String[] args){


        new Main();




    }

}
```

Comment: `super.paint(g);` would be the first mistake. You should clear the buffer yourself

Comment: Let me try and clarify. The Canvas is a child of the frame, it’s position is offset by the frame borders, by calling super.paint, your asking the frame to paint itself onto the Graphics, the black bars are actually the areas which are normally covered by the window decorations

Comment: Awesome!  I changed super.paint(g) to canvas.paint(g) and it is working as expected now.

Comment: No, don’t do that either, just paint to the buffer, that’s the point

Answer (score 1):

You need to go read [the JavaDocs for `BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html), which a number of important tutorials and examples on `BufferStrategy`

A `BufferStrategy` is a means to perform "page flipping", which is independent of the regular painting system.  This provides you with "active" control over the painting process.  Each buffer is updated off screen and the pushed onto the screen when it's ready.

This generally does not involve the component's own painting system and the intention is to avoid it.

This means you should NOT be calling `super.paint(g)` on the `JFrame` or `canvas.paint`.  In fact, as a general rule, you should NEVER call `paint` manually.

Each time you want to update a buffer, you will be required to "prepare" it.  This typically means filling it with some base color

So, based on the example from the JavaDocs, you could do something like...

```
// Check the capabilities of the GraphicsConfiguration
 ...

 // Create our component
 Window w = new Window(gc);

 // Show our window
 w.setVisible(true);

 // Create a general double-buffering strategy
 w.createBufferStrategy(2);
 BufferStrategy strategy = w.getBufferStrategy();

 // Main loop
 while (!done) {
     // Prepare for rendering the next frame
     // ...

     // Render single frame
     do {
         // The following loop ensures that the contents of the drawing buffer
         // are consistent in case the underlying surface was recreated
         do {
             // Get a new graphics context every time through the loop

             // Determine the current width and height of the
             // output
             int width = ...;
             int height = ...l
             // to make sure the strategy is validated
             Graphics graphics = strategy.getDrawGraphics();
             graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
             graphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);    
             // Render to graphics
             // ...

             // Dispose the graphics
             graphics.dispose();

             // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents
             // were restored
         } while (strategy.contentsRestored());

         // Display the buffer
         strategy.show();

         // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer was lost
     } while (strategy.contentsLost());
 }

 // Dispose the window
 w.setVisible(false);
 w.dispose();
```

Now, personally, I'd prefer to use `Canvas` as the base, as it gives a more re-usable solution and it's easier to determine dimensions from